# Dropdownlist from EditorTemplates does not return value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, mvc-editor-templates, tag-helpers

I created a simple SingleSelectDropdownlist view model to avoid writing html and classes over and over again. This class has a property called Options (where options are stored for the dropdown) and SelectedValue (a string property to store selected value) and a Placeholder property.

```
@model SingleSelectDdl
@{
    var options = new SelectList(Model.Options, "Value", "Text", string.Empty);
}
<select asp-for="SelectedValue" asp-items="options" class="form-control" placeholder="@Model.Placeholder"></select>
<span asp-validation-for="SelectedValue"></span>
```

After upgrading to ASP.NET Core 1.1.0 I noticed that the SelectedValue property doesn't return any value anymore, it just returns an empty string no matter what I do.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Please don't force tags into the title. It's sufficient to note inside the quesiton body that you are using ASP.NET Core 1.1. The asp.net-core tag already address and mark the question as an ASP.NET Core question. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging on how to correctly use tags. Also please note that [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] is the correct tag name for ASP.NET Core MVC

Comment: The code in your view looks fine, although the 4th parameter of the `SelectList()` constructor is pointless, and the 2nd and 3rd parameters suggest `Model.Options` is already a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (so why create a duplicate). Show you models - does `SelectedValue` have a getter/setter?